# How to modify the menu icon when unfolded?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I want to change the main menu icon with awesome font:

- https://fontawesome.com/icons/plus-circle?style=solid when folded.
- https://fontawesome.com/icons/minus-circle?style=solid when unfolded.

Since the update to make awesome 5, it does not work anymore.

```
#block-menuprincipal li.dropdown > a i:before {
    content: '\f055';
}

#block-menuprincipal li.dropdown > a[aria-expanded=true] i:before {
    content: '\f056';
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwalA.png)

```
<a href="/boutique" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true"><svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-minus-circle fa-w-16 fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="minus-circle" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M256 8C119 8 8 119 8 256s111 248 248 248 248-111 248-248S393 8 256 8zM124 296c-6.6 0-12-5.4-12-12v-56c0-6.6 5.4-12 12-12h264c6.6 0 12 5.4 12 12v56c0 6.6-5.4 12-12 12H124z"></path></svg><!-- <i class="fas fa-minus-circle fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> --> Boutiques</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep. Font Awesome changed a few things around.  You have a couple of options, however.  The new, recommended way to handle these situations is to build the classes for changing icons yourself.  [See here](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/web-fonts-with-css#pseudo-elements).  In that section of their documentation, you can see that they built an icon **without prefixing the class with `fa`.** Instead, they just used the class `.login` and added the needed styles to that.

Alternatively, you can still use their [font-family based implementation](https://fontawesome.com/get-started/web-fonts-with-css), although, it is not recommended (by them at least).  Notice on that page near the bottom of the blue header section that there are four tabs.  You're currently using "SVG with JS".  You would just need to switch to the steps for using "Web Fonts with CSS".

Lastly, I'm not sure if this will work or not, but there's also a shim that they provide.  If you have a lot of legacy code, [using the shim](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/upgrading-from-4) may allow you to still use pseudo class `content` values or it may not.  I haven't tested this, but it's at least good to know that this is out there.